# How do I pick up text values of child nodes when parsing XML with ElementTree

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, beautifulsoup, xml-parsing, elementtree

I have an XML shopping feed with a bunch of products, see below. If I'd parse this with beautiful soup, to create a pandas dataframe, I'd use something like this:

```
def parse_shopping_feed(feed_xml):
    #response = requests.get(feed_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(feed_xml, "xml")
    all_products = []
    for item in soup.find_all("item"):
        new_product = {
            "id": item.id.string,
            "title": item.title.string,
            "description": item.description.string,
            "google_product_category": item.google_product_category.string,
            "product_type": item.product_type.string if  "product_type" in item else "",
            "link": item.link.string,
            "availability": item.availability.string,
            "price": item.price.string,
            "brand": item.brand.string
        }
        all_products.append(new_product)
    feed_df = pd.DataFrame(all_products)
    return feed_df
```

Now, Beautiful Soup is too slow for one of these feeds (around 300mbs) so have started looking at ElementTree which is supposed to be faster. However I can't for the life of me figure out I would recreate this code with ET.

How do I loop through all of the item tags and grap their ID and title for example?

My current best guess is something like this, but I don't get how pick up each ID and title.

```
xml_file = open('shopping_feed.xml')
for event, element in ET.iterparse(xml_file, events=None):
    for child in element:
        print(child)
    element.clear()
```

Any suggestions?
To be clear, my end goal is the dataframe, so if there's a way to just convert it directly that'd be great!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0">
<channel>
    <title>Feed XYZ</title>
    <description></description>
    <link></link>
    <item>
        <g:id>10000005</g:id>
        <title><![CDATA[TEst Item XYZ                                           ]]></title>
        <g:google_product_category>Food and stuff</g:google_product_category>
        <g:product_type><![CDATA[Details &gt; Food and stuff]]></g:product_type>
        <g:adwords_grouping><![CDATA[Food and stuff]]></g:adwords_grouping>
        <link>https://www.abc.se/abc/abc</link>
        <g:image_link>https://www.abc.se/bilder/artiklar/10000005.jpg</g:image_link>
        <g:additional_image_link>https://www.abc.se/bilder/artiklar/zoom/10000005_1.jpg</g:additional_image_link>
        <g:condition>new</g:condition>
        <g:availability>out of stock</g:availability>
        <g:price>155 SEK</g:price>
        <g:buyprice>68.00</g:buyprice>
        <g:brand>ABC</g:brand>
        <g:gtin>8003299920846</g:gtin>
        <g:mpn>ABC01 AZ</g:mpn> 
        <g:weight>0 g</g:weight> 
        <g:item_group_id>10000008r</g:item_group_id>
        <g:color>Blue</g:color>
//100s of thousand of products
```

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution:

```
import lxml.etree as et
xml_data = open('feed.xml')
xml_data = xml_data.read()
data = et.fromstring(xml_data.encode("utf-8"))
items = data.xpath('//item')
​
all_products = []
prefix = "{http://base.google.com/ns/1.0}"
for item in items:
    new_product = {
        "id": item.find(prefix+ 'id').text,
        "title": item.find('title').text, 
        "google_product_category": item.find(prefix + 'google_product_category').text,
        "product_type": item.find(prefix + 'product_type').text,
        "link": item.find('link').text,
        "availability": item.find(prefix + 'availability').text,
        "price": item.find(prefix + 'price').text,
        "brand": item.find(prefix + 'brand').text
    }
    all_products.append(new_product)
```